# "scale" and "scaling" cover the same subject matter

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

There are two tags - [scale](/questions/tagged/scale) and [scaling](/questions/tagged/scaling) which both allow questions regarding image scaling. I believe that these two tags need to be merged and then a synonym created from one to another.

[scale](/questions/tagged/scale) - The scale tag is mostly used for questions that relate to proportional resizing of images or UI elements.

[scaling](/questions/tagged/scaling) - Scaling refers to the image manipulation function of re-sizing an image. For issues to do with handling increasing workload gracefully in software or network components, see "scalabilty".

The tag wiki from [scale](/questions/tagged/scale) would probably be the most suitable for the merged tag once completed.